# Running command in R shell with embedded quotes

Tags: r

I want to run a dos command on my Windows machine from within an R-script.
The command is:

```
robocopy C:/myproject E:/backup /MIR /XD ".git"
```

It synchronizes the directory *myproject* on C with the *backup* directory on E without syncing the *.git*-directory. This runs fine in a dos window.

The r line for running this I use is:

```
mydos <- "robocopy C:/myproject E:/backup /MIR /XD '.git'"
shell(mydos)
```

But that doesn't work properly (it does the robocopy but syncs the exempted git-directory).
I tried playing around with shQuote (and interchanging the quotation marks)

```
shell(shQuote(mydos, type = "cmd"))
```

or

```
shell(shQuote(mydos, type = "cmd2"))
```

But although robocopy does sync, it also copies the .git-directory.

Any idea how to make this work?

Cheers

Renger